# Autoload and use simple HTML dom external librarie in Codeigniter 3.0.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having problems with including / using external libraries in CodeIgniter 3.0. So this is what i did so far:

I have placed simple_html_dom.php file in my application/libraries folder

[image: Including file and auto loading it]

Then i'm auto loading it with this line of code in

```
/*
example of CI 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('user_agent' => 'ua');
*/

$autoload['libraries'] = array('simple_html_dom' => 'shd');
```

And this is my controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $html = $this->shd->str_get_html('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');
        var_dump($html);
        die();
        $this->load->view('parser');
    }
```

Which provides me an error of:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom::str_get_html()
Filename: controllers/Parser.php
Line Number: 8
```

Documentation of simple_html_dom can be found on this [link](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

To me it looks like librarie gets loaded, but i can't use its functions.
I hope somebody can help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. After checking documentation of simple html dom, i found out that you can also use object oriented way. So my controller looks like this now:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<html><body>Hello!</body></html>');
var_dump($html);
```

And i have result:

```
object(simple_html_dom)[17]
  public 'root' => 
    object(simple_html_dom_node)[18]
      public 'nodetype' => int 5
      public 'tag' => string 'root' (length=4)
      public 'attr' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(simple_html_dom_node)[19]
              ...
      public 'nodes' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(simple_html_dom_node)[19]
              ...
      public 'parent' => null
      public '_' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int -1
          1 => int 4
      public 'tag_start' => int 0
      private 'dom' => 
        &object(simple_html_dom)[17]
  public 'nodes' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(simple_html_dom_node)[18]
          public 'nodetype' => int 5
          public 'tag' => string 'root' (length=4)
          public 'attr' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'children' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'nodes' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'parent' => null
          public '_' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          public 'tag_start' => int 0
          private 'dom' => 
            &object(simple_html_dom)[17]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$this->load->library("simple_html_dom"); //class name should come here
```

And make sure `simple_html_dom.php` class name is `simple_html_dom`

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more?
Because if i just load this library inside my controller i get same problem.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem because this simple_html_dom file has many classes inside file?

Comment: what should we do then if the simple_html_dom file has many classes...? Do we need to separate each class into each file accordingly ? @Valor_

Answer (score 0):

Try this  -

$autoload['libraries'] = array('simple_html_dom');

Comment: Sorry, same problem
Message: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom::str_get_html()

Comment: I think problem is in your file. Not in library autoload.

Comment: Yes, i'm just thinking about this right now. 
Because simple_html_dom has many classes inside file. If i try this file without codeigniter, it's working, But running in codeigniter will be a problem.

Comment: I have found a solution. You have to make object first, then you can use functions! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like that:

```
$this->load->library("simple_html_dom");
$this->simple_html_dom->your_method();
```